# WebApi read exsisting JSON file - C#

Tags: javascript, c#, json, azure, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to create a webapi that reads an exsisting JSON file and then returns it as json object so i can use Javascript to populate the data as HTML to this site. http://pptlbhweb.azurewebsites.net/

The JSON file gets updated as i have a temperaturelogger that logs the events to an eventhub - Streamanalytics - saves as JSON in blob storage (Azure)

Here is the JSON file: https://pptlbhstorage.blob.core.windows.net/temperature/0_7622a22009224c78a46c0b2bc0a3fd82_1.json

If you look on the JSON file it needs to append "]" at the end (This is what i think) in this way i can get a valid JSON object that the WebApi returns.

I have already created a WebApi so i can use URL to get data. http://pptlbhwebapi.azurewebsites.net/api/test

Something similar for getting temperature would be for example:
http://pptlbhwebapi.azurewebsites.net/api/temperature

**The fix:**

Add this to your api controller:

```
[System.Web.Http.Route("api/readandreturnjson")]
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ReadAndReturnJsonAsync()
{
    // object to return through the API (it'll be serialized by WebAPI)
    object obj = null;
    // WebClient used to download the JSON file
    using (var wc = new WebClient())
    {

        var url =
        "https://pptlbhstorage.blob.core.windows.net/temperature/0_7622a22009224c78a46c0b2bc0a3fd82_1.json";
        // Used to hold and add a ']' to the downloaded JSON
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.Append(await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url));
        builder.Append("]");
        // Deserialize the now valid JSON into obj
        obj =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(builder.ToString());
    }
    // return the json with 200 Http status.
    return Ok(obj);
}
```

In Global.assax:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Remove(GlobalConfiguration.Configu‌​ration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
[System.Web.Http.Route("api/readandreturnjson")]
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ReadAndReturnJsonAsync()
{
    // object to return through the API (it'll be serialized by WebAPI)
    object obj = null;
    // WebClient used to download the JSON file
    using (var wc = new WebClient())
    {

        var url =
        "https://pptlbhstorage.blob.core.windows.net/temperature/0_7622a22009224c78a46c0b2bc0a3fd82_1.json";
        // Used to hold and add a ']' to the downloaded JSON
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.Append(await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url));
        builder.Append("]");
        // Deserialize the now valid JSON into obj
        obj =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(builder.ToString());
    }
    // return the json with 200 Http status.
    return Ok(obj);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, When i paste this into my testController i get the question between choosing System.web.http.httpgetattribute and System.web.mvc.httpgetattribute. Am i doing this right?

Comment: Since you're using WebAPI then you should choose `System.Web.Http.httpGetAttribute` @yellowborat

Comment: Okay, then i put this in my http get in testController?

Comment: Does my edit makes sense? or am i completly misunderstanding the concept ?

Comment: @yellowborat yes. that about it. See my new edit. After adding the `Route` you can call the method at `http://yoursever/api/readandreturnjson`

Comment: i have published it.. if you go to the link it just says: an error occured

Comment: is it possible to move this to an discussion or chat? 
http://pptlbhwebapi.azurewebsites.net/api/readandreturnjson it just says an error has occured

Comment: It doesn't show the detailed error message as a security measure. [You should check the IIS logs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713763/).

Comment: I've tried to get the error logs to english, but it doesn't make any sense in my language.. here is my repo https://github.com/BennyHoang/JSON

Comment: @yellowborat add this line `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Remove(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);` to Global.asax in the `Application_start()` method

Comment: I've created a pull request on your Github project.